# How do I find a constant for a polynomial so its roots are reflective around a linear function?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

How can I find all complex numbers $w$ so that the roots of the following polynomial are reflected around a linear function $f(x)$ $$p(q) = q^2-4q+w = 0$$

If I want to find all the complex numbers $w$, for which the roots of the polynomials are reflective around, say $f(x) = -x+2$, how would I go about doing that?

***Mark my words!** The text below is a bit confusing, just showing my work if it lights any spark in someone's mind, hopefully it does! I really want to solve this problem, seems like something that would be very useful to know how to solve.*

---

I have been playing around and noticed some few things.

- If we have a function $g(x)$ which is perpendicular to $f(x)$ then all roots in a polynomial must either come in pair as points on $g(x)$ line **OR** a root will be sitting on the $f(x)$ line *[double root?]*; this is the requirement for the condition in the title of this question
- This means in my case that all roots will be in the form of $\alpha=r\cdot e^{i\cdot(\pi/4+k\pi)}+ z$ where $z$ is the point at which $f(x) = g(x)$. And $r=\sqrt{(\alpha_1-\Re z)^2+(\alpha_1-\Im z)^2}$, where $\alpha_1$ is a root.

  The reason behind this is that the perpendicular function $g$ would have a negated slope from $f$ which in my case had the slope of $-1\cdot x\implies g(x) = x + m$ where $m$ would be chosen according to a root found. Drawing this, one easily sees the roots must be found at $\theta=\pi/4\ or\ -3\pi/4$ with mid-point in $z$, and a radius of $r$.
- I have also tried using Vietas formulas with no luck as Vietas formulas requires all coefficients to be known for a full solution. (Obviously)

#### Edit 1. I might add!

I'm still looking for a complete solution for all possible $w$ where the roots of $p$ are reflective around $f(x) = -x+2$

Comment: What do you mean by "the roots of the polynomials are reflective around, say f(x)=−x+2"? Can you give an example of one such $w$ to clarify?

Comment: I actually can't give an example; however, let me clarify. Find a complex number $w = (a+ib)$ which when put into the polynomial $p(z)$ i.e. $q^2-4q+w=0$ or $q^2-4q+(a+ib)=0$, in turn means the roots for $p(z)$ are each other's reflection around the line that passes through the points $3-i$ and $2i$ i.e. $f(x) = \frac{2-(-1)}{0-3}x+ 2 = -x + 2$

Comment: Edited the body text. Still looking for all solutions for $w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Q.F., the roots of
$$p(q) = q^2 + B q + C$$
are
$$r_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}\left(-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4 C}\right)$$
(here $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is any branch).

If $p$ has a double root, which the above shows happens iff $B^2 = 4C$, in which case the double root is at $-\frac{B}{2}$, then any reflection through a line containing $2$ maps each root to the other. So, henceforce suppose $p$ has two distinct roots.

Now, the reflection that exchanges $r_{\pm}$ is exactly a reflection across the perpendicular bisector of the line segment with vertices $r_{\pm}$: By construction this line contains the midpoint $\frac{1}{2}(r_+ + r_-) = -\frac{B}{2}$, and is orthogonal to the vector $\sqrt{B^2 - 4C}$, so it equation is
$$\sqrt{B^2 - 4C} \cdot \left(z + \frac{B}{2}\right) = 0,$$
where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product $a \cdot b := \Re(\bar{a} b).$

On the other hand, we can write the line $ax + by = c$ through $-\frac{B}{2}$ in complex form as
$$(a + bi) \cdot \left(z + \frac{B}{2}\right) = 0.$$ So, reflection across this line exchanges the roots of $p$ if
$$a + bi = \sqrt{B^2 - 4C},$$
that is, if
$$(a^2 - b^2) + 2abi = B^2 - 4C.$$

In your case, $B = -4$, and $C = w$, and we can take $a = b = 1$, and substituting and rearranging gives
$$w = \frac{1}{4}(16 - 2i) = 4 - \frac{1}{2}i.$$ Of course, we can just ask well take $a = b = \lambda$ for any nonzero (real) $\lambda$, which leads to the general solution
$$w = 4 - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 i, \qquad \lambda \neq 0,$$
which we can suggestively write as
$$w = 4 + \mu i, \qquad \mu < 0.$$

Comment: Thank you. I also did find the value $w=4$, but I didn't quite understand the last part with $\zeta$, so I just wanted to ask, can $\sqrt{4-w}(z-2) = 0$ be used to find the remainder of possible values on $w$? If so, how would I continue from there?

Comment: Do you know how to write the real and imaginary parts of the square root of a given complex number?

Comment: Going into polar form, then using de Moivres formula?

Comment: NB we can already conclude from the above that any value of $w$ (except $2$) determines a line, and any line through $2$ determines a one-parameter family of values $w$ for which the roots of $p$ are reflected through the line.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: When you say that any line through $2$ determines a one-parameter family of values, I understand that the roots of $p$ lay on this line, which would be perpendicular to $f$, i.e. the roots are reflected through the line. But how do I determine all lines that go through $2$? I'm trying to visualise what this means, I'm a little unknowing right there.

Or easier said, how would I determine all possible $w$, which are not equal to $4$?

Comment: I might add, if it wasn't completely clear I'm sorry, I only want to find the $w$ which makes the roots of the polynomial $p$ be reflective around the line $f(x) = -x+2$

Comment: I added some more comments explaining how to solve the problem for a particular line $ax + by = c$.